# how to remove modulus signs after integrating

Tags: integration

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + k\frac{t^2 -3t + 2}{t+1}y = 0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \  y(t_0=0)=A>0\\
-\int \frac{k}{y} dy = \int (t-4 + \frac{6}{t+1})  dx
$$

After integrating the above how do you express $y$ in terms of $t$?

When you integrate $\frac1y$ you get $\ln |y|$  - how do you remove the modulus sign (without squaring the expression) to get one single expression for $y$ in terms of $t, k$ and $A$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Usually one looks at the initial condition. In most "physical" problems, $y$ is naturally non-negative, so there is no need of  modulus sign.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to remove absolute value signs is to substitute in the definition: if you have $|z|$ in your problem, then you split the problem into two subproblems: one where you add the condition $z \geq 0$ and one where you add the condition $z \leq 0$. In the first, you can replace $|z| = z$ and continue on. In the latter, you replace $|z| = -z$.

(occasionally, three subproblems $z > 0$, $z < 0$ and $z = 0$ is more convenient)

P.S. don't forget that when you antidifferentiate $1/y$ to get $\ln|y| + C$, $C$ is only guaranteed to be 'locally constant': in general, $C$ is a different constant on the $y>0$ and $y<0$ parts.

Many problems where these issues come up (particularly when differentiation/integration of $1/y$ is involved) naturally limit themselves to a single one of the subproblems. e.g. if you're integrating $1/y$ because you want to find

$$ \int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{dy}{y} $$

then you can limit yourself to the $y<0$ subproblem.

Comment: as A>0 should I limit myself to the y>0 subproblem? for the y<0 subproblem I cannot find the constant as A>0